# Should we have another publicity push?

Tags: discussion, publicity

I don't have access to what statistics SE uses to determine if genealogy.se is trending up or stagnating. I only have my aperiodic looking at [beta home page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history). From an unscientific analysis of that data, it seems to me that our user base is slowly growing but our questions per day and our visits per day are somewhat stagnant. We seem to have a solid core of experts willing to answer questions (evidenced by our high answer ratio) but we need more people willing to ask questions and more content to attract hits - I assume the two are related.

Is it time to do another publicity push? I suspect the blogger push when we first started mainly got experts to stay around (which is very good) but the casual users didn't see enough to attract them. Now we have more content so they'd be more likely to 'stick' (at least I hope so). Can whoever got blogosphere talking in the first push do it again?

Comment: Some stats (not the ones the mods use, these are less accurate as they use a small sample size) http://www.quantcast.com/genealogy.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd say it's too early to worry about "stagnating", it's a pretty normal part of the growth curve in a site so young. It is, however, never too early to push to get more users and great content on the site.

Answer (score 4):

The number of visits is generally pretty flat since November, but that is not all that unusual for a site as this stage while we continue to compile a collection of high-quality questions that will attract users through Google search. The number of questions and answers slowed a bit over the holidays, but that's not all that unusual either. But regardless of the stats, it's never a bad idea to keep thinking about promotional activities to raise engagement.

Comment: "that is not all that unusual for a site as this stage" - is that based on empirical data?

Comment: @Duncan Yes, it is. It is quite normal for a site in beta to experience a temporary slough at this time of year. That is in fact one of the reasons for the Winter Bash-- to keep user participation up.